# Обработка событий клавиатуры

Tags: java, graphics

Я создал подставку в окне JFrame, как изображение. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на стрелочку влево,подставка двигалась влево,а при нажатии на клавишу вправо,двигалась вправо.Я попробовал реализовать это,но у меня не очень получается. Весь код ниже.

**Game**

```
public class Game { // главный класс 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GetFruit");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Stand stand = new Stand();
        KeyboardObserver observer = new KeyboardObserver(stand);
        frame.addKeyListener(observer);
        frame.add(stand);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(700,500);
    }
}
```

**Stand**

```
public class Stand extends JPanel{ // Подставка
    private StandDirection direction;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Stand(){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\images\\p.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Неверный путь к изображению.");
        }
    }

    public void setDirection(StandDirection direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public StandDirection getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    private int x = 250;
    private int y = 350;


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
        while(true) {
            if (this.getDirection() == StandDirection.LEFT) {
                x -= 20;
                repaint();
            } else if (this.getDirection() == StandDirection.RIGHT) {
                x += 20;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**StandDirection**

```
public enum StandDirection { // enum со значениями
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
```

**KeyboardObserver**

```
public class KeyboardObserver implements KeyListener{ // Отслеживает нажатия клавиш
    private Stand stand;

    public KeyboardObserver(Stand stand) {
        this.stand = stand;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            stand.setDirection(StandDirection.LEFT);
        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            stand.setDirection(StandDirection.RIGHT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , понял,учту на будущее.

Comment: так писать нельзя. вы блокирует процесс обработки событий своим бесконечным циклом.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman посоветуйте,как правильно реализовать мою идею. Спасибо.

Comment: начните с разделения модели (положения и направления движения подставки) и отображения. рекомендую почитать вот эту книгу http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/ , там подробно описано как решать подобные задачи

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, спасибо,почитаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас несколько ошибок в коде, смотрите комментарии, исправленная версия:

```
class Stand extends JPanel { // Подставка
    private StandDirection direction;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Stand() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\images\\p.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Неверный путь к изображению.");
        }
    }

    public void setDirection(StandDirection direction) {
        this.repaint();//тут вызываем перерисовку
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public StandDirection getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    private int x = 250;
    private int y = 350;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); //очищаем ранее нарисованное
        //убираем вечный цикл, как сказал @Mikhail Vaysman
        if (this.getDirection() == StandDirection.LEFT) {
            x -= 20;
            //repaint(); //это рекурсия, убираем ее
        } else if (this.getDirection() == StandDirection.RIGHT) {
            x += 20;
            //repaint(); //это рекурсия, убираем ее
        }
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Все работает почти как я хочу. Но не стирается предыдущий рисунок. и получается одна большая черная полоса.

Comment: @mrKott обновил ответ

Comment: Все отлично. Но появилось 2 проблемы. 
1. при зажатии какой - либо клавиши движения изображение начинает мерцать.
2.Допустим,я 3 раза нажал влево,когда я нажимаю вправо, картинка двигается влево,и только на второе нажатие вправо.

Comment: @mrKott заменил `this.paint(this.getGraphics());` на `this.repaint();`

Comment: Все отлично,спасибо. Можете объяснить различие this.paint(this.getGraphics()); от this.repaint(); ?

Comment: К сожалению не могу((, т.к. не пишу приложений на swing, а просто увидел ошибки в Вашем коде. Первая ссылка в гугле дает такой [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875572/paint-repaint-paintcomponent)

Comment: спасибо за статью,прочитаю. Вы мне очень помогли.)